# Why does my 30-second sound plays only 4 seconds in my LibGDX project?

Tags: java, android, loops, audio, libgdx

I tried to set a backgroundsound in my LibGDX project. I wrote in the `Asset.java` file following code:

```
public static void playBackgroundsound(){
     backgroundsound.loop();
}
```

After this I went in the `MainMenuScreen.java` file and and wrote this line in the `onClick()` of the start Button from the game:

```
Assets.playBackgroundsound();
```

The sound is 30 seconds long and should only loop after its played completely.
The problem is that it loops after 4 seconds.
What is the Reason for it and how can I solve this problem??

Here is the GitHub project:
https://github.com/DaFaack/FlappyBibi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`background1.mp3` may be of 30 sec not 
`backgroundsound.mp3` check your assets folder.

---

Mp3 files have some decoding delay at the start.

You can use `.wav` file instead of `.mp3` for less delay also for `Sound` Effect you should use small `.mp3` file.

In my suggestion for background sound, you should use `Music` instead of `Sound`.

According to [wiki](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Sound-effects) :

> Sound effects are small audio samples, usually no longer than a few
>   seconds, that are played back on specific game events such as a
>   character jumping or shooting a gun.

Music is -

> For any sound that's longer than a few seconds it is preferable to
>   stream it from disk instead of fully loading it into RAM. Libgdx
>   provides a Music interface that lets you do that.

Loading and playing music is as simple as `Sound` :

```
Music music = Gdx.audio.newMusic(Gdx.files.internal("data/mymusic.mp3"));
music.setLooping(true);
music.play();
```